# using actionButton + insertUI in R shiny modules to create multiple inputs

Tags: r, shiny, module, shiny-server

I created a module to help me accept 1)an excel file 2)a text input for the sheet name and 3) a text input for the range.

I want to be able to use this module in an App such that each time I click on the action button (AddExcelDataButton in the code below), it allows me to input a different file.  I also need to be able to extract the contents of the file later.

I tried the below code in the main App, but it is throwing me the following errors
error1: The UI is linking all the inputs "inside the button"
error2: I am unable to figure out how to "access" or retrieve the filenames later in the code.

Any help in doing this the right way is highly appreciated please!

**CODE FOR THE MODULE:**

```
importExceldataUI <- function(importExceldata){
  tagList(
    
    tags$div(
      HTML(paste0("<b>", "Enter Your Data Here"))
    ),
    
    tags$div(
    fileInput(inputId = "ImportExcelFile",
              label = "Excel File",
              multiple=FALSE),
    style = "display:inline-block; vertical-align:top"
    ),# end of tags$div for fileInput ImportExcelFile
    
    tags$div(
    textInput(inputId = "ExcelSheetName",
              label = "Sheet",
              value="Data",),
    style = "display:inline-block; vertical-align:top"
     ),#end of tags$Div for texinput-ExcelSheetName
    
    tags$div(
    textInput(inputId = "ExcelSheetRange",
              label = "Range",
              value = "C5:BN1000"),
    style = "display:inline-block"
    )#end of tags$div for textInput - sheetrange
 )
}


importExceldataServer <- function(importExceldata){
  moduleServer(importExceldata, function(input, output, session){
 })  
}
```

**CODE FOR MAIN APP**

```
importExceldataApp <- function(){
  ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
     actionButton(inputId = "AddExcelDataButton", label = "Click here to add Excel Data"),
     
  )#emd pf mainpanel
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session){
       observeEvent(input$AddExcelDataButton, {
        insertUI(selector = "#AddExcelDataButton",
                 ui = importExceldataUI(paste0("file",input$AddExcelDataButton))) 
       })#end of observeEvent
    
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}


importExceldataApp()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors you need to fix:

1. to use modules, you must have IDs for both UI and server. For each pair, they must have the same ID.
2. For ids in module UI, you must use namespace `NS`.
3. For `insertUI`, default is insert into the selector, apparently, you don't want to insert inside a button, you need to add after the button, so you need have `where` argument, please read the help file of this function.

You should read more about [shiny modules standards](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html)

Here is the working code:

```r
library(shiny)

importExceldataUI <- function(id){
    ns <- NS(id)
    tagList(
        tags$div(
            HTML(paste0("<b>", "Enter Your Data Here"))
        ),
        tags$div(
            fileInput(inputId = ns("ImportExcelFile"),
                      label = "Excel File",
                      multiple=FALSE),
            style = "display:inline-block; vertical-align:top"
        ),# end of tags$div for fileInput ImportExcelFile
        
        tags$div(
            textInput(inputId = ns("ExcelSheetName"),
                      label = "Sheet",
                      value="Data"),
            style = "display:inline-block; vertical-align:top"
        ),#end of tags$Div for texinput-ExcelSheetName
        
        tags$div(
            textInput(inputId = ns("ExcelSheetRange"),
                      label = "Range",
                      value = "C5:BN1000"),
            style = "display:inline-block"
        )#end of tags$div for textInput - sheetrange
    )
}


importExceldataServer <- function(id){
    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
        observeEvent(input$ImportExcelFile, {
            req(input$ImportExcelFile)
            print(input$ImportExcelFile$datapath)
        })
    })  
}

importExceldataApp <- function(){
    ui <- fluidPage(
        mainPanel(
            actionButton(inputId = "AddExcelDataButton", label = "Click here to add Excel Data"),
        )#emd pf mainpanel
    )
    
    server <- function(input, output, session){
        observeEvent(input$AddExcelDataButton, {
            insertUI(selector = "#AddExcelDataButton", where = "afterEnd",
                     ui = importExceldataUI(paste0("file",input$AddExcelDataButton))) 
            importExceldataServer(paste0("file",input$AddExcelDataButton))
        })#end of observeEvent
        
    }
    
    shinyApp(ui, server)
}


importExceldataApp()
```

So to read the path of uploaded file, just use `input$ImportExcelFile$datapath`, `datapath` is the file location. Here in my code, I just print it out, you can do other things.